# Refworks Bibliography Output Style Choice, for Springer?

Tags: reference-managers, citation-style

Refworks.com can output a bibliography, based on an output style list, which includes several hundred different output style choices.  [Refworks Output Style List](https://www.refworks.com/content/path_learn/output_style.asp)

However, the list does specifically include "Springer": see i.e.  [Springer Bibliography Requirements](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/instruct/authors/authors.pdf)

What is a similar Refworks output style choice/item, which is similar to the Springer requirements?

Comment: Sorry, I browsed the list and I'm confused: are you worried that the list DOES NOT explicitly mentions Springer?

Comment: I had not realized that "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" implicitly refers to Springer, so the Answer worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Springer" document that you linked contains specific instructions for how to contribute to Springer Computer Science Proceedings. It also says:

> You will find here Springer’s guidelines for the preparation of
>   proceedings papers to be published in one of the following series, in
>   printed and electronic form

That means that those instructions are valid for all the journals and publications listed below.

So try to look for one of those style (i.e.: Lecture Notes in Computer Science) and it should work.

Comment: Yes, Refworks did list "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" (which I had not seen), thx!!!